# accessing std::map iterator from enclosing class fails

Tags: c++, inner-classes, stdmap

Update: Turns out below code actually runs. My issue could be something unrelated although I see no difference between real code. Still figuring out.

This simple c++ code is failing at runtime with exception. I think I am missing some kind of access related restriction in constructor for maps. I have the class defined like so

```
class Child {
  public:
    Child() {
      auto itr1 = this->child_map.begin();  // works
    };
    ~Child() {};

    std::map<int,int> child_map;
    std::vector<int> child_vector;
};

class Parent {
  public:
    Parent();
    ~Parent() {};
    Child child_one;
};

Parent::Parent() {
  auto itr2 = this->child_one.child_vector.begin(); // works
  auto itr3 = this->child_one.child_map.begin(); // null pointer exception
}

Parent parent_obj;
```

Calling iterator on map fails only from parent constructor. Vector iterator works just fine. I already tried adding friend class both ways and still got same exception. if I looked through the source, _Get_data() is returning nullptr and failing on call of _Lmost() below

```
_NODISCARD iterator begin() noexcept
    {   // return iterator for beginning of mutable sequence
    auto& _My_data = this->_Get_data();
    return (iterator(_My_data._Lmost(), _STD addressof(_My_data)));
    }
```

tried searching online and no luck so far. what am i missing here?

Comment: [works fine for me](http://ideone.com/aBPnhP), after making the `Child()` constructor public so that the `parent_obj` can actually be instantiated. Calling `begin()` on an empty container is legal, which makes me think you are not showing your real code that reproduces the error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry the constructors are actually public and still failing. edited the code.

Comment: I stripped down a lot of the code to enter the bare structure. Let me paste a minimal reproducible example in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Had an incorrect memset on a class pointer which was overlooked. Surprisingly only std::map  iterator failed due to this